# What happens to the book after a creature is released from Scribe's Binding?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spellcasting-focus

[Scribe's Binding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scribe-s-binding) imprisons a creature in a book, that then is filled with its "memories and knowledge".

If the creature is released, does the book still contains the "memories and knowledge" of the creature?

The book is not destroyed because it is a spell focus.

Comment: (O, good heavens. The implications of that spell…! I mean, what if the creature prepared spells from a spellbook? Heck, *what if the creature read an actual book?* It's a book that contains every book the creature read, every song it ever heard, every drama it ever saw. I can even imagine other party members volunteering to be affected by the spell so the remaining party members can look up information they forgot. GMs, I hope your notes are in order! Wow.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Talk about a soul-sharing experience... coming up: [How long does it takes for the book to fill](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109447/11402)

Answer (score 1):

This reader suspects that the a creature freed from the effect of a [*scribe's binding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scribe-s-binding) spell does *not* leave behind in the focus book a record of its memories to that point. This is because the first line of the spell's description says that it "binds a single creature into a prepared book, sustaining it in suspended animation and filling the book with its experience and knowledge." That phrase after the comma describes what "binding a… creature into a… book" *means*; hence, after the creature's freed, the creature's is *not* "in suspended animation and filling the book with its experience and knowledge."

Thus, this GM would rule that after the creature's freed, the book's emptied of the creature's memories. (By the way, apparently that book, once emptied, *can* be reused.)

Were this *not* the case and a creature's memories *remained* in the book even *after* the creature's freed from its binding, the book's possessor could continue whimsically manipulating the creature's memories with impunity, the creature never knowing nor being able to resist. While this GM has a thorough and healthy respect for 9th-level spells, this seems a bridge too far. (Of lesser concern, were that the case, then the book couldn't be reused, the creature's memories having "fill[ed] the book.")