# How long does it take for a Scribe's Binding book to be filled?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

[Scribe's Binding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scribe-s-binding) writes a tome with all the "memories and knowledge" of a imprisoned creature.

But how long does it takes for the book to be filled? Is it instantaneous?

The spell has a duration of "permanent", but I suppose it is regarding the length of the imprisonment.

Answer (score 7):

The book that's the focus of the spell [*scribe's binding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scribe-s-binding) fills with the subject's memories upon the spell's resolution. Were there some lag between the subject failing (or forgoing!) its saving throw against the spell and the focus book filling with the subject's memories, the spell would mention that. As it stands, the spell doesn't mention that, so the book fills up immediately.

The spell's [duration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) may be permanent—that's how long the spell's effect endures—, but the spell's [casting time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Time) remains 1 standard action, and, at the end of that casting time, the spell's effect comes into existence.

Comment: hehe. Now it is time to play catch and release with some nobles. Those vault passwords were never that easy to obtain.

Comment: @Mindwin The hard part will be *finding* that password in the 40-year-old noble's 14,600-or-so-page book. Ugh. *So* boring!